# .Net Framework re installation on application servers

Tags: .net

Microsft.net framework update is not getting installed in two of our application(MIM) server.When windows team checked that,they found there are multiple versions of .net frame work is installed in both server due to that the update push is not working.
As per windows team, reinstalling or installing new version of.net framework would fix the issue.

My question here is, would there be any impact to the application when reinstalling/Installing a newer version of .Net framework ?

Comment: Try it in your test environment. Use a VM or something.

Comment: Depends on which version of .NET the application was coded against and which version is being installed. There were breaking changes in C# 5: https://davefancher.com/2012/11/03/c-5-0-breaking-changes/